# Workaround to Left Outer Join adding extra rows, comma separated column instead?

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I'm very new to SQL but keen to learn (using SQL server).

My Data table has:

[Keyword] , [Source] , [Visits] columns

Keyword column has duplicate values.

Examples of values found in [Keyword]

```
google

google analytics

how to use google analytics

bing

bing vs google
```

My KeywordDefinition table has:

```
[Keyword Branded ID]     [Keyword Branded Group]

google                 branded google
bing                   branded bing
```

Keyword column has only unique values so this would be the key.

I'm using a LEFT OUTER JOIN to insert the [Keyword Branded Group] into my Data table that in effect assigns a label to every keyword based on whether it matches google or bing.

```
SELECT 

ISNULL(c1.[Keyword Branded Group],'Other Branded') AS [Keyword Branded Group],
a.*

FROM [mychoice-data-b9BwZvd] a

LEFT OUTER JOIN [mychoice-keyworddims] c1 ON a.[Keyword] LIKE '%'+ c1.[Keyword Branded ID] +'%'
```

However, my problem is that this results in extra rows based on the fact that say "bing vs google" matches both Google and Bing. This is my understanding anyway.

Someone suggested that I can retain my original number of rows in the Data table and have the new column [Keyword Branded Group] as a comma separated value 'Branded Google, Branded Bing' instead of ending up with more rows.

Sadly they didn't say any more than that and I don't know which SQL commands to look up! Can anyone help? I just need someone to point me in the right direction!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think is to move the outer join into a UDF. First create a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAllKeywords (@Keyword varchar(max)) RETURNS varchar(max)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @return varchar(max)
    SET @return = ''

    SELECT @return = @return + ',' + [Keyword Branded Group]
    FROM KeywordDefinition
    WHERE @Keyword LIKE '%'+ [Keyword Branded ID] +'%'

    IF (LEN(@return) > 2)
        RETURN substring(@return, 2, len(@return) - 2)
    ELSE
        RETURN 'Other Branded'
END
```

Then you can put the UDF in as a subquery:

```
SELECT dbo.GetAllKeywords(a.Keyword), a.*
FROM [mychoice-data-b9BwZvd] a
```

Comment: Nice solution. You could eliminate the leading comma by doing this: 
SET return = null;
SELECT @return = coalesce(@return + ', ', '') + [KeywordBrandedGroup]

Comment: Hi Diana, Thank you for that! I'm trying it now (monday morning fresh brain! ;-)) but I get an error "The last statement included within a function must be a return statement"